# Pascal ABC.NET. Встречено '.', а ожидалось ';'

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Код:

```
program NESCAFE_Automat;

{$mode objfpc} {$H+}

uses CRT;

procedure Main;
procedure ASugar;
procedure ACream;
procedure Final;

var
  cofe: string[12];
  sugar: integer;
  cream: integer;
  a: string[3];
  cofetmp: string[25];
  b: integer;

procedure Main;
begin
  { Coded by DirBeer }

repeat
    b:=0;
    cofe:='';
    sugar:=0;
    cream:=0;
    a:='';
    cofetmp:='';

    ClrScr;
    TextColor(9);
    writeln('Select cofe:');
    writeln('1. Cappuccino [240 ml]');
    writeln('2. Cafe Au Lait [180 ml]');
    writeln('3. Cappuccino Intenso [240 ml]');
    writeln('4. Espresso [intensity 5, 50 ml]');
    writeln;
    a:=readkey;
    if (a = #49) then begin cofe:='cappuccino'; b:=1; end;
    if (a = #50) then begin cofe:='cafeaulait'; b:=1; end;
    if (a = #51) then begin cofe:='cap_intenso'; b:=1; end;
    if (a = #52) then begin cofe:='espresso'; b:=1; end;
  until b = 1;

  ASugar;
end;

procedure ASugar;
begin
  repeat
    if (cofe = '') then begin Main; end;
    b:=0;
    ClrScr;
    TextColor(9);
    writeln('Sugar?');
    writeln('1. Need');
    writeln('2. No');
    writeln;
    a:=readkey;
    if (a = #49) then begin write('Sugar (grams): '); read(sugar); writeln; b:=1; end;
    if (sugar < 1) then begin { no sugar } sugar:=0; b:=1; end;
    if (a = #50) then begin b:=1; end;
    until b = 1;
    ACream;
end;

procedure ACream;
begin
  repeat
    if (cofe = '') then begin Main; end;
    b:=0;
    ClrScr;
    TextColor(9);
    writeln('Cream?');
    writeln('1. Need');
    writeln('2. No');
    writeln;
    a:=readkey;
    if (a = #49) then begin write('Cream (grams): '); read(cream); writeln; b:=1; end;
    if (cream < 1) then begin { no cream } cream:=0; b:=1; end;
    if (a = #50) then begin b:=1; end;
    until b = 1;
    Final;
end;

procedure Final;
begin
  repeat
    {Final order}
    if (cofe = '') then begin Main; end;
    b:=0;
    ClrScr;
    TextColor(9);
    writeln('Your order: ');
    if (cofe = 'cappuccino') then begin cofetmp:='Cappucino 240 ml'; end;
    if (cofe = 'cafeaulait') then begin cofetmp:='Cafe Au Lait 180 ml'; end;
    if (cofe = 'cap_intenso') then begin cofetmp:='Cappucino Intenso 240 ml'; end;
    if (cofe = 'espresso') then begin cofetmp:='Espresso 50 ml'; end;

    writeln(cofetmp, ' ', sugar, ' g of sugar, ', cream, ' g of cream');
    writeln;
    writeln('Wait!');
    writeln;
    readkey;
    b:=1;
  until b = 1;

  Main;
end;

begin Main; end.
```

В чём я сделал ошибку на 110-ой строке?

Comment: на какой строчке происходит ошибка?

Comment: Вспоминается, что после end. надо перейти на новую строку

Comment: В процедуре ACream вместо этого NESCAFE_Automat.Main; кажется должно быть просто Main;

Comment: Да не, всё равно не работает.

Comment: Ок, когда думал что в этом ошибка, раньше ругался компилятор на процедуру Sugar, пришлось вместо него сделать ASugar.

Comment: Поэтому и делал Программа.Процедура

Comment: Код читается плохо. Надо делать отступы

Comment: какая строка 110 в этом коде?

Comment: последняя.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае ошибка в описании процедур:

```
procedure Main;
procedure ASugar;
procedure ACream;
procedure Final;
```

не хватает ключевого слова [`forward`](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Forward_Referencing)

```
procedure Main; forward;
procedure ASugar; forward;
procedure ACream; forward;
procedure Final; forward;
```

Comment: @DirBeer, если помогло можешь отметить ответ галочкой рядом с ответом